# Azure DevOps Build Validation Pipeline Error Reporting

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, ado

I have an Azure DevOps build validation pipeline (yml) that runs multiple stages. Each stage has a single job that runs a few different tasks. Each stage is an independent test and they run in parallel. The pipeline is setup as a build validation policy on the main branch. Whenever a pipeline is created or updated, this pipeline triggers and will run the tests. My issue is when multiple stages fail in the pipeline, only one error gets reported back to the pull request.

So what I tried doing is setting a final stage that depends on all the other stages. That stage calls the ADO API, gets the error messages from all the previous sages and then reports all the errors in one message, but for some reason, it just picks a random error to report back to the PR and not the error from this final stage.

For example, here is my pipeline run:

[image: Pipeline]

As you can see, it ran a unit_test stage, a type_check stage and then finally a final_verification stage after the first two were complete. However, if you look at the pull request, it shows the error message of the type-check stage.

[image: Pull Request]

My questions are:

Is there any control over what message gets sent back to the pull request?

Is there a way to report all the errors back to the pull request?

Is there something I can do differently to achieve what I'm looking to do? Basically tell the user of the PR all the build issues without needing to click into the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying: *Each stage has a single job that runs a few different tasks. **Each stage is an independent test** and **they run in parallel.***

Simply split the current multistage pipeline into 3 different pipelines for each stage and then create 3 different build validations on the PR, it will be more meaningful.

You will have 3 different checks on PR and there will be clear information on which failed and which passed.

Comment: Yeah, I though about doing that. In my example, I show 2 stages, (or 2 tests), but there will be around 8 or so stages. And we have like 8-10 repos that will run these tests. So I was trying to make it so each repo would only need a single pipeline. So we end up with 8-10 pipelines instead of 64-80 pipelines :D